# WPF XMLDataProvider do not work for union of XPath

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, xpath

The XMLDataProvider is not returning outcome for XPath query having union. Please see my problem statement at bottam after the code.

In WPF XMLDataProvider, I am using below somestrings.xml as below,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<MyRoot>
<App1>
    <Common>
    <ApplicationName>Online Games</ApplicationName>
    </Common>
   <Screen1>
    <SelectGameshButtonName>Select Games</SelectGameshButtonName>
   </Screen1>  
   <Screen2>
    <FinishButtonName>Finish Purchase</FinishButtonName>    
   </Screen2>  
</App1>
</MyRoot>
```

The XAML code is

```
<Window x:Class="WPF_XML.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:gl="clr-namespace:System.Globalization;assembly=mscorlib"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <XmlDataProvider x:Key="SomeStrings" Source="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/somestrings.xml"  XPath="MyRoot/App1/Common|MyRoot/App1/Screen1"/>

    </Window.Resources>  
    <Grid >
        <Label Content="{Binding Source={StaticResource SomeStrings}, XPath=ApplicationName}" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="38,82,0,0" Name="lblName" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="107" />
        <Button Content="{Binding Source={StaticResource SomeStrings}, FallbackValue=oops, XPath=SelectGameshButtonName}" Height="24" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="169,82,0,0" Name="btnSelect" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="104" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Using XMLDataProvider I am trying to assign display text to the controls from xml file.
So Here are the observations I have,

```
XPath="MyRoot/App1/Common"  then label gets value.
XPath="MyRoot/App1/Screen1"  then button gets value
```

Since I want both of the control should get value in single query so use the union of XPath as,

```
XPath="MyRoot/App1/Common|MyRoot/App1/Screen1"
```

But i see only label is getting updated.

Why XMLDataProvider is failing to return the button name to the binding.

Is this an issue with  XMLDataProvider or i am missing something?

Thanks

**EDIT**

Although setting XPath="MyRoot/App1" at XMLDataProvider and setting control content binding as below,

```
XPath="Common/ApplicationName|Screen1/ApplicationName" 
XPath="Common/SelectGameshButtonName|Screen1/SelectGameshButtonName"
```

works functionally ! But I do not want to use this approach,

1. Reason#1

from performance perspective. It will load all screens xml node in XMLDataProvider instead of just the common and screen1.

1. Reason#2

Developer working on the screens should only use node name for the control without any prefix specification. They should not care where the string is located. Because over the time the strings may get moved to common.

Answer (score 0):

Your `XmlDataProvider` return multiple items, but since you use UI controls for displaying single item (Label and Button, as opposed to ListBox, ItemsControl, etc) you get only the first item displayed by both UI controls (the `<Common>...</Common>` element).

The problem is not because of using XPath union. Even if you don't use union, if you have multiple elements with the same name in the XML, using your approach only the first element will be displayed.

To fix the problem, you can declare the `XmlDataProvider` using this XPath :

```
<XmlDataProvider XPath="MyRoot/App1" x:Key="SomeStrings" Source="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/somestrings.xml"  />
```

Then use following XPath for your `Label` and `Button` :

```
<Label Content="{Binding Source={StaticResource SomeStrings}, XPath=Common/ApplicationName}" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="38,82,0,0" Name="lblName" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="107" />
<Button Content="{Binding Source={StaticResource SomeStrings}, FallbackValue=oops, XPath=Screen1/SelectGameshButtonName}" Height="24" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="169,82,0,0" Name="btnSelect" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="104" />
```

Comment: if you see my edit section. this the approach i do not want to take.

Comment: Please see my explanation in EDIT part of the question

Comment: Also i do not have multiple elements with same name as you mentioned. Every element is unique. XMLDataProvider is trying to bind only first node's(common) child nodes of the query result. It ignores the second node's(Screen1) child nodes. Ideally The XMLDataProvider should return a single node result with child's from both XPath but in reality it does not. Isn't it a shortcoming of XMLDataProvider or I am missing something?

Comment: 1. I don't say you have multiple element with the same name, but imagine if you have and guess which element will be displayed? The first. 2. "Ideally The XMLDataProvider should return a single node result..." Nope, it simply return 2 elements in your case so the label and button has to choose which one to display in they default to the first. 3. You can try using `ListBox` with `ItemsSource` bound to your `XmlDataProvider`. You'll see both elements are displayed, that proves the problem is not in the XPath join.

Comment: For 1,

By the design the common and a screen strings can not have same name.
   so ambigutiy in selection is do not exist. For 2&3
I am not saying the XPath join is incorrect. List box do show elements nodes into it(as it understand collection).
Now here is moment of truth List box binding can see it but label or button level binding using XPath unable query this collection beyond the first node. 
why? One logical reason can be XmlDataProvider data output is not single xml but collection of fragmented xml nodes. cont..

Comment: So when we do binding level XPath 
query, it essentially traverse the XMl of the first node and can not go to second as it can not do collection traversal.

I tried a test. In c# I brought all child nodes under first parent node of the collection and then found that
all binding are resolved and i could see contents on every controls as queried at their binding.
so my code above worked . cont..

Comment: But  I do not want to do this. rather I expect XMLDataProvider or data binding framework should give me it out of the 
box. When it see the XPath at binding level it should implicitly go thorugh all nodes with that query and resolve all bindings.